# Blender hanging when starting to render

Tags: rendering

Blender is freezing when I start to render. If I am lucky I might get one image to render, but when I try to render a second time it hangs. Sometimes it just hangs on the first render.
It switches to render window, then just hangs, no information displayed and PC fans start going full blast like it is rendering, but nothing happens any more. I can leave for ages and nothing (usually each image takes about 8 seconds).

Trying this on two different PCs and both the same. I have various versions of the files as save at different stages. Files where previously working well, about a month ago both machines where running for a week creating about 70000 images / frames from these files.
I have updated to 3.1 past month, but tried 2.93 and it is the same.
Have tried updating Nvidia driver on one machine but the same.
Main machine is running on Win10 with 32GB ram and 3090RTX.
Have tried older iterations of the scene and same issue. Tried switching off denoise and even switching to evee but same issue.
If I create a simple scene or try other scenses I have saved they work ok.

A little frustrated as all was working fine previously.
Any help appreciated? Maybe there is a cache folder or similar I need to clear?
Thank you

Update:
Not sure if it is related but running debug modes I see a lot or messages like:
WARN (bke.anim_sys): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v310\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\anim_sys.c:401 BKE_animsys_rna_path_resolve: Animato: Invalid path. ID = 'Body',  'pose.bones["ControlHand.L"].scale[2]'

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided a .blend file, some screenshots, or an explanation of any computationally intensive things in your project. Either way, I'm surprised that such a powerful machine would hang like this, so it could possibly be a problem/bug with blender. If you haven't already, you might be able to try hiding objects in the render until you find a culprit.

Comment: Thanks Hayden. I can't share the .blend, but a good suggestion with hiding objects. I am trying that and thought I had locked it down to a curved object but maybe not as it just hung again. One thing strange is that everytime I open any file, it defaults back to rendering type of none, rather than Cuda. Even if I change it back and save the file it resets on next opening.

Comment: Sorry meant OptiX, can't see where to edit.